# Position buttons on bottom of card group in Bootstrap4

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have the following code:

```
<h2 id="yachts" class="mt-0">Our Yachts</h2>
<div class="card-group">
    {{ $pages := sort (where $.Site.RegularPages "Section" "boats") "Weight" "asc" }}
    {{ range $pages }}
        <div class="card">
            <img src="{{ .RelPermalink | safeCSS }}{{ .Params.heroimage | safeCSS }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body clearfix">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ .LinkTitle }}</h4>
                <p class="card-text border-light border-top border-bottom">
                    <span class="row">
                        <span class="col-6 text-muted text-left">
                            {{- partialCached "icons/users.svg" . -}}{{ .Params.pax }}
                        </span>
                        <span class="col-6 text-muted text-right">
                            {{- partialCached "icons/bed.svg" . -}}{{ .Params.bunks }}
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>                    
                <p class="card-text">{{ .Description }}</p>
                <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}" class="card-link stretched-link btn btn-outline-dark float-right">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{ end }}
</div>
```

(The logic stuff inside of the `{{` tags is Hugo templating markup (Golang) which is irrelevant at this point).

The result of this code looks like this in one of the uses:

[image: layout sample]

I would like to position the buttons on the same level (bottom right of each card).

I tried doing it via position relative on the card and position absolute on the buttons, but that positions them at their current location, not the real bottom of the card. What would be the "flex way" to tell these buttons where they belong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Bootstrap offers the `card-footer` class that does exactly what I wanted to achieve. Using `bg-light` or our own class for styling then can make it look right.

```
<div class="card-footer bg-light">
    <a href="{{ $page.RelPermalink }}" class="card-link stretched-link btn btn-outline-dark btn-block">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

[From the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-groups):

> When using card groups with footers, their content will automatically line up.

Answer (score 0):

Try min-height for .card-text

```
.card-text{
  min-height:250px;
}
```